# unity3d Property is reset to default while script is running

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting, static, reset

I'm newbie in Unity3D scripting and trying to learn how it works internally for my simple projects, what are the best practices. Here I have a simple scene with a cube in it and trying to animate it, going left to certain point in time, then reversing back to negative value and then back in loop (on x axis). Direction is set in class public boolean property. By default it is negative value (which means it should go in positive direction, sorry for confusion). If it is positive it should go negative. However I have noticed that when I change this boolean value in Update method of script, it reverses back to original value? (when set to true, default is false). Then my object gets stack between going true and false and not moving in any direction. However if I set this property as **static property** in class, it does not resets and works just as intended (loops fine). I do not know why is it resets and here I'm completely confused.

```
public class CubeAnim : MonoBehaviour
{    
    public bool directionnegative;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float nv = 25.0f * Time.deltaTime;

        float posx = transform.position.x;

        if (posx > 20.0f)
        {
            if (!directionnegative)
            {
                directionnegative = true;
            }
        }
        else if (posx < -20.0f)
        {
            if (directionnegative)
            {
                directionnegative = false;
            }
        }

        if(directionnegative)
        {
            nv = -(nv);
        }

        transform.Translate(nv, 0, 0);

        deltaTime += (Time.deltaTime - deltaTime) * 0.1f;
        float fps = 1.0f / deltaTime;
        string log = "posx: " + transform.position.x + "\ndir: " + directionnegative + " transx: " + nv + "\nfps: " + Mathf.Ceil(fps).ToString();
        Debug.Log(log);
    }
}
```

And if I declare directionnegative as static bool script works fine and cube animation is properly going in one direction, then in another direction, then reverses:

```
        public static bool directionnegative;
```

Comment: Are you by chance using a custom editor for `CubeAnim`?

Comment: is it possible that it is just changing every frame forth and back so it appears to be stuck?

Comment: Please show your scene hierarchy and show the Inspector for your object with `CubeAnim` on it.

Comment: @BenRubin I'm not sure what you mean by custom editor?

Comment: @derHugo Had checked in debugger and in log, it does not stuck until reversing back? Did you had a chance to look it yourself?

Comment: @BenRubin Does this help: https://ibb.co/xDxsPTp  If you need more information please notify me.

Comment: @BenRubin Here is the complete Unity project, use 7zip to decompress: https://easyupload.io/tdzxig

Comment: Why do you have more than one `CubeAnim` component attached to the same object?  That's your problem.  They're each moving the cube independently and interfering with each other.

Comment: @BenRubin Thanks for the help! I'm noob and I did screwed the scene and object.. did not knew that I was in the wrong... Had removed excess of the scripts and now cube animation works just fine. Thanks! Had accepted your answer.

Comment: @VladacusB Glad it's working now.  FYI the reason it was working when you made the property `static` is because then each instance of `CubeAnim` was using the same instance of `directionnegative` so they'd all move in the same direction each frame.  When each script was using their own instance of `directionnegative`, some were moving the cube to the left and some were moving the cube to the right during the same frame.